# Calling setBackgroundResource() twice with different frame animations

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to show two different animations. It works fine with the first one. But when I stop the first animation and call  setBackgroundResource() second time with my second animation ( and then call start() ) it shows only the first frame. 
Is it possible to call setBackgroundResource() twice to set different animations?

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        ImageView imgView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation1);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView
                .getBackground();

        frameAnimation.setCallback(imgView);
        frameAnimation.start();


            //Schedule the timer

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    showAnimation2();
                    }
         }, 20000);
    }//if hasFocus

}

/**
 * Show second animation
 */ 
public void showAnimation2(){
    ImageView imgView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imgView
                .getBackground();
     // stop first animation
     frameAnimation.stop();

     imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation2);
     frameAnimation.setCallback(imgView);

    //start second animation
     frameAnimation.start();
     // here I see the first frame of second animation only
}
```

I also tried to play with setVisible(...) but it doesn't help

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: I would appriciate any help 'cause I'm stuck with this problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using two ImageView and switching between them. I use setVisibility() method to hide one view with the first animation and show the second view.